# Get changes between two builds in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to get the changes between two builds using this code:

```
var changes1 = buildClient.GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync("PipelineTest", 2, 3).Result;
```

This returns no elements. However when I try to get the changes via the web-portal for build 3 I get a change:

[image]

I also tried `build.GetBuildChangesAsync("PipelineTest", 3)` which gave me no results neither.

I have to notice thogh, that the pipeline is stored within `Repo1`, whereas the change was done on `Repo2`.

How can I get all changes between two builds regardless on the repository they have been committed in?

I am using `TeamFoundationServer.Client` 16.170.0

Comment: You pass the `buildId`  - `fromBuildId` and `toBuildId`
  as a part of the URL and get the collection of changes (`Change[]`) in response.
Please refer [Get Changes Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-changes-between-builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT already tried that. Doesn't return any elements. That applies to both the `changes`- as as well as the `workitems`-endpoint.

Comment: Are you using git Repo ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT yes, an azure-git-repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we already found out getting the changes or workitems between two builds on a multi-repository-structure isn't yet supported on Azure Devops. There's a [feature-request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Get-workites-between-builds-for-pipelin/1554491) for that, though.

In order to workaround that I inspected how the graphical interface retrieves the information and noticed there is some undocumented function called `HierarchyQuery`. After some trial and error I got that function to work within my app. There are a couple of information we need to provide here, though.

The first of course is some authentication - in my example I use a private access token. This is identical to authenticating the "normal" API. The second point here is some data that we should use in our POST-request. This mainly contains the repo for which we want to get changes (`"artifactAlias":"Repo2"`) as well as the build-id we want to inspect (`"currentRunId":3`). As we have multiple repos, we need to loop them, which I omited here, you get the idea, don't you?

Lastly we need to parse the response in order to get the workitemid. From there we can again use the normal API to query the associated item.

**However notice this is completely undocumented and no public API.**

```
string workItemId;
var json =  "{\"contributionIds\":[\"ms.vss-traceability-web.traceability-workitems-data-provider\"],\"dataProviderContext\":{\"properties\":{\"artifactAlias\":\"Repo2\",\"currentRunId\":3,\"useSnapshot\":true,\"sourcePage\":{\"url\":\"https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/PipelineTest/_traceability/runview/workitems?currentRunId=3\",\"routeId\":\"ms.vss-traceability-web.traceability-run-workitems-hub-default-route\",\"routeValues\":{\"project\":\"PipelineTest\",\"controller\":\"ContributedPage\",\"action\":\"Execute\",\"serviceHost\":\"MyServiceHost\"}}}}}";
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json;api-version=5.0-preview.1;excludeUrls=true;enumsAsNumbers=true;msDateFormat=true;noArrayWrap=true");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", myPAT))));    
    
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery", content).Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        dynamic r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
        workItemId = (string)r["dataProviders"]["ms.vss-traceability-web.traceability-workitems-data-provider"]["data"][0]["id"];
    }
}

var connection = new VssConnection(clientBaseAddress, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
var wiclient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var workItem = wiclient.GetWorkItemAsync(projectName, Int32.Parse(workItemId)).Result;
```

Comment: Whats the ServiceHost parameter in the payload, how do I get that?

Comment: @KevinLee eeehm, good question, don't remember sadly. Can you provide an arbitrary string maybe?

Comment: @KevinLee you may however also track the request being send to the function when doing that manually from the UI. That should give you the exact syntax and the params needed.

Comment: @KevinLee okay, I re-checked that and it seems it's some kind of an organization-specific identifier. So just get yours by firing the reuqest from the UI and fecth the params using your devtools.

Comment: Got it, so it should be constant then.

Comment: This works great, but if my observation is correct, it does not work for the repo containing the pipeline (named "current pipeline"), but only for all further repos.